# Wordpress can I manually add columns in users table and display it in the default manage user plugin and registration form?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

How would I go about doing this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding new columns to the WordPress database, you might want to use the `wp_usermeta` table. It is used to store any kind of data about your users (just like the `wp_postmeta` for your posts and pages).

To add fields on the registration form you can use the `user_new_form` action which is triggered by the admin form or the `register_form` on the registration form on the website.

Then, hook into the `insert_user_meta` filter (triggered after the user save) and add the user meta that you submitted with your form.

Finally, as you probably need to display those values in the user edit form, try to hook into `edit_user_profile` to add your custom fields in the user profile page.
When posting the form, the user update function will automatically trigger the same function you used to add the user meta.